# Getting move events from embedded Java applet

Tags: java, events, applet, awt

Is it possible to get an event when an embedded Java applet changes position because the browser is moved?

The obvious method doesn't work:

```
applet.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {               
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("componentMoved");
    }
    // snip
});
```

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like the wrong approach to achieving ..anything.  BTW - What is it that you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I have a popup window, that I would like to move along with the applet.

Comment: Hmm.. Applets & pop-up windows are usually a bad idea, but thanks for explaining. In that case, you will want to move the floating window on browser move **or** page scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `getLocationOnScreen()` for any fixed element it the applet in a loop.  Note that will also fire when the page containing the applet is scrolled.

Comment: This is probably the best solution. Unfortunately this seems to have some quirks, too: on (at least) Safari and Firefox on OS X getLocationOnScreen() is not updated until the applet regains focus.

Comment: That is too bad.  If you post an SSCCE of your best attempt, I'll have a look at it.  (I can at least confirm if the code works on Windows/FF.)

Comment: Don't worry about it. It works fine on Windows, but since there was no good general solution, I think we will just leave any popup windows alone if the user should move the applet.

Comment: Good idea.  Trying to get applets behaving 'just right' in the slew of browsers on various OS can lead to madness.